# What spells are associated with my sorcerer's Dragon Ancestry, for the purpose of the Elemental Affinity feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, damage-types

What spells would be associated with my Draconic Bloodline sorcerer's *Dragon Ancestor*, for the purpose of the 6th-level Elemental Affinity feature?

I picked Brass Dragon as my ancestry; would it be fire spells?

Comment: Hello Nick. I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding the question. Could you rephrase it? What part of Draconic Ancestry is it that you need help with?

Comment: Dragon Bloodline instead of Draconic Ancestry? https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#SorcerousOrigins

Comment: I've reworded your question to be clearer. Is it as you intend?

Comment: Are you referring to the 6th level class ability for the Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer?  Do you have a copy of the Players Handbook?  If not, what in the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf=page#44) are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @Grosscol -- the bloodline is refers to *Draconic Ancestry*, it defines which dragon blood you have

Comment: @ravery I thought draconic ancestry was a heading under dragonborn and draconic bloodline was a heading under sorcerer.

Comment: @Grosscol -- Draconic bloodline is a class of sorcerer, it gives a draconic ancestry,  elemental affinity, and a few other draconic traits. Kind of a diluted dragonborn

Comment: @ravery gotcha.  Looks like draconic ancestry shows up twice and means different things in each case.  For dragonborn, it's a breathweapon; and for sorcerers, it's a damage type affinity.

Comment: @Grosscol - right, the ancestry gives the element used by the abilities, which are different as you stated.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, it's fire

The [Draconic Bloodline sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline)'s Dragon Ancestor feature tells you to pick a type of dragon to serve as your dragon ancestor, with a table associating each dragon type with a particular damage type:

> At 1st level, you choose one type of dragon as your ancestor. The damage type associated with each dragon is used by features you gain later. (SRD, p. 44)

The Draconic Ancestry for Brass points to fire. (SRD, p. 45)

The subclass then grants the Elemental Affinity feature at 6th level, which boosts damage for spells of that damage type (and lets you spend a sorcery point to gain resistance to that damage type for an hour):

> Starting at 6th level, when you cast a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell. At the same time, you can spend 1 sorcery point to gain resistance to that damage type for 1 hour.

You add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll for a fire spell.

[From your comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132439/sorcerer-elf-dragonblood-line-elemental-affinity/132446?noredirect=1#comment330309_132446):

> So is it just one spell a day? I get to apply that to?or with every
>   long rest?

No limit.  It is on each fire spell that you cast.
Example: if you cast the cantrip *fire bolt* ten times during a few combats, on each casting you get the bonus.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, it is fire

*Elemental Affinity* states:

> Starting at 6th level, when you Cast a Spell that deals damage of the type associated with your Draconic ancestry, you can add your Charisma modifier to one damage roll of that spell. At the same time, you can spend 1 sorcery point to gain Resistance to that damage type for 1 hour. [roll20 Compendium](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#content)

*Draconic Ancestry* gives:

> Black  Acid
> Blue    Lightning
> Brass   Fire
> Bronze  Lightning
> Copper  Acid
> Gold    Fire
> Green   Poison
> Red     Fire
> Silver  Cold
> White   Cold  [roll20 Compendium](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#content)

Thus, a Brass Dragon Ancestry would give bonus damage to any spell that does fire damage when *Elemental Affinity* is gained at 6th level.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, Fire Spells

Specifically, *[draconic bloodline](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DraconicBloodline)* indicates that spells that do fire damage are "fire spells".